# GluonFX SceneBuilder display not matching gluonfx:run display

Tags: java, android, ios, javafx, gluon

I'm building a mobile app with gluon FX. I'm using scenebuilder to help create my UI with FXML. However, the SceneBuilder preview UI looks very different from the UI I get when running it with gluonfx:run through Maven. What is causing this?/What can I do to fix it? I've attached images below.

SceneBuilder:

[image]

mvn gluonfx:run

[image]

Comment: You might check your icon locations, as built, against the expected values. See [_How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61531317/230513)